# I disable autolayout, now my view size and screen size are 320 not the larger size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscreen

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGFloat starSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / 5;;
    NSLog(@"star size: %f", starSize);
```

I'm testing on an iPhone 6 Plus simulator and Star size is logging as 64. 64*5 = 320. My screen should be bigger than 320.

How do I get the correct screen size?

EDIT: I added launch images. My screen size is still 320.

Comment: What do you get in `-viewDidAppear`? Layout hasn't necessarily set the screen to its final size when `-viewDidLoad` is called. If the view has width 320 in the xib that probably why

Comment: The size is "inferred" -- it shows as 320 yes but I can't change it.

Comment: Actually, after thinking about it a bit, that's probably rubbish. `UIScreen` should be returning the same size irrespective of what's going on with the xib/storyboard. It certainly does in a minimal example app. Maybe it's something to do with having screen scaling set up by a launch image of a  fixed size - the mechanism by which pre -iPhone 6 apps autoscale to the new screen sizes

Comment: Yes, just got 64 on the iPhone 6 plus simulator using a 640x1136 launch image. But turning autolayout back on doesn't change anything so it may not be exactly the same

Comment: I think your app is still running the iPhone 5 screen mode. Have you updated your LaunchImage to include the one needed for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+?

Comment: Doh, I keep forgetting about this. Thank you Angela

Comment: I had the file. Still shows.